# How can I get data from a fake REST API site into my application?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I'm trying to get data from a fake REST API for testing purposes. I've tried several of them but though I copy the code they specify and it works on their sites I can't get them to work in my application. I think this might be a cross domain issue, but if it is, I have no idea how to fix it.

```
<script>
$( "#query" ).submit(function( event ) {
    var root = 'http://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net';
    $.ajax({
        url: root + '/posts/1',
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need an external domain? Just fetch from a local file. All you need to do is some minor apache/nginx config for URL rewrites.

Comment: Not hard to find ones that are CORS enabled

Comment: Have you looked at [mockjax](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax)?

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for your thoughts. Just to clarify, I'm fetching (or not as the case may be) from an external domain because once I get the test code working I'll be replacing it with a call to the NASA API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a **`CORS issue`**, try using this public url

```
$( "#query" ).submit(function( event ) {
    var root = 'https://api.github.com';
    $.ajax({
        url: root,
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Robert. The code you've come up with doesn't work for me as is, but if I change it to act on a button click rather than a form submit it works fine. The reason is probably screamingly obvious to anyone but me. Any thoughts?

Comment: make sure .submit is being called, if that is true then it will work the same as the button. Make sure input type="submit" is in your form or a button.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working by changing 'type=text' in the form to type='search'.